# Using Linq to populate ViewModel from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, mapping, viewmodel

I am populating my viewmodels from linq queries.  I have a method to retrieve a list of plans that looks something like this

```
        public static IEnumerable<PlanViewModel> GetPlans()
        {
        using (var context = new RepEntities())
        {

            var query = (from p in context.Plans.Include("StatusCommon")
                         join r in context.RealEstateDetails on p.ReId equals r.ReId
                         select new PlanViewModel
                         {
                             PlanName = p.PlanName,
                             ...
                             LastUpdated = p.LastUpdated,
                         });

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Where you see the ellipses are about 30 other properties. Now I want to build a method to return a single Plan. The method would be virtually the same except that it will contain a where clause to specify a plan Id. I would like to refactor this code so that I am not duplicating the mapping of the Model to the ViewModel. However, I'm not finding a way that allows me to do this.  Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how to properly code this so that here isn't so much duplication?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try creating repository add methods GetAll which does currently you are doing , add GetById method which you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Either use reflection to populate the fields, or go with a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). I'd definitely recommend using AutoMapper though, it will keep your code a lot cleaner.

Another possibility is using [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converters.

It pretty much depends where you want to have the code:

- Utility class (reflection)
- Models/ViewModels (implicit or explicit)
- Anywere (AutoMapper)

Comment: Jeroen,

Automapper looks like the solution.  Do you happen to know how it handles Navigation Properties? Suppose a Plan has one or more Buildings.  So the source would be  Plan.Buildings where Buildings is a List<Building>.  Then my destination (ViewModel) would be  PlanViewModel.Buildings whereas Buildings is a List<BuildingViewModel>.  Can Automapper handle this sort of nested projection?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. You can find a lot of information in their wiki; the relevant page is this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings